# How to embed a LinkLabel control in a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, browser, linklabel

I am exploring the feasibility of embedding a LinkLabel control in a WebBrowser control. Could somebody tell me if is feasible or not?

If it is feasible, then how to implement it. Looking for code snippets.

~neerAJ

Comment: using c# to create a form with Webbrowser as a control, I am wondering if I could embed a LinkLabel control in the WebBrowser control which could be used to open other forms (and not urls)

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.  A WebBrowser control displays HTML, it cannot contain any Winforms controls.

You could consider modifying the HTML with the WebBrowser.Document property, use the `<a>` element.  You can detect a click with the HtmlElement.Click event.  You'd need to have a pretty good idea what the original HTML looks like to know where to insert the element.